# Does low GPU utilization indicate bad fit for GPU acceleration?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, gpu, torchvision

I'm running some [GPU-accelerated PyTorch code](https://github.com/avinashpaliwal/Super-SloMo) and training it against a custom dataset, but while monitoring the state of my workstation during the process, I see GPU usage along the following lines:

[image: GPU usage in task manager]

I have never written my own GPU primitives, but I have a long history of doing low-level optimizations for CPU-intensive workloads and my experience there makes me concerned that while pytorch/torchvision are offloading the work to the GPU, it may not be an ideal workload for GPU acceleration.

When optimizing CPU-bound code, the goal is to try and get the CPU to perform as much (meaningful) work as possible in a unit of time: a supposedly CPU-bound task that shows only 20% CPU utilization (of a single core or of all cores, depending on whether the task is parallelizable or not) is a task that is not being performed efficiently because the CPU is sitting idle when ideally it would be working towards your goal. Low CPU usage means that something other than number crunching is taking up your wall clock time, whether it's inefficient locking, heavy context switching, pipeline flushes, locking IO in the main loop, etc. which prevents the workload from properly saturating the CPU.

When looking at the GPU utilization in the chart above, and again speaking as a complete novice when it comes to GPU utilization, it strikes me that the GPU usage is extremely low and appears to be limited by the rate at which data is being copied into the GPU memory. Is this assumption correct? I would expect to see a spike in copy (to GPU) followed by an extended period of calculations/transforms, followed by a brief copy (back from the GPU), repeated ad infinitum.

I notice that despite the low (albeit constant) copy utilization, the GPU memory is constantly peaking at the 8GB limit. Can I assume the workload is being limited by the low GPU memory available (i.e. not maxing out the copy bandwidth because there's only so much that can be copied)?

Does that mean this is a workload better suited for the CPU (in this particular case with this RTX 2080 and in general with any card)?

Comment: I would suggest using a tool like TechPowerUp's GPU-Z to monitor GPU utilization under Windows. I am not sure how useful Windows' built-in monitoring is. Your application is a compute app, so I wouldn't expect "3D" utilization to be high, and if the app is well written (minimizing copying), I also would expect "Copy" to be fairly low. You might also want to check whether PyTorch is actually using the GPU at all.

Comment: If you're loading data from the hard disk on the fly it's possible that this is the bottleneck so the system spends very little time utilizing the GPU and a lot of time reading from disk. Considering the link you sent is a video recognition task, videos can be very slow to decode and are notorious for bottlenecking.

Comment: You might have found it yourself by now, when you click on one of the down facing arrows next to 3D, Copy, Video Encode or Video Decode, you can select other performance metrics of your GPU. One of them is CUDA. This will usually show significantly higher utilization. But I have to agree that pyTorch is not always saturating GPUs to their full potential. That probably requires some manual tweaking